# Reporting services and custom library

Tags: reporting-services

Greetings, 
In my Reporting Services report I've added reference to my custom library. It works fine. I can display the string which is returned from my custom library method as follows:

```
=ClassLibrary1.MyClass.Parse("harry potter")
```

Above code works fine - it should return SQL query based on passed parameters. My question is, how can I use this code in my DataSource. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM =ClassLibrary1.MyClass.Parse(@searchedPhrase)
```

But the above code does not work and the error is returned :"`Incorrect syntax near ="`

Comment: Are you sure that this solution is operable?
I'm not sure.

Comment: finally I made it. I've assigned this method to hidden field as follows =Code.MyClass.Parse(Parameters!queryParameter.Value) then in my DataSource I created a parameter which references to this hidden field. I little bit tricky but it fulfill its role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I made it. I've assigned this method to hidden field as follows `=Code.MyClass.Parse(Parameters!queryParameter.Value)`

then in my DataSource I created a parameter which references to this hidden field. I little bit tricky but it fulfill its role